# Set up a public web page for free

Tags: website, web, web-application, publishing

Is there a reliable website which allows you to publish a web page of mainly static text content?

I just need to put up a page for others to see it, even if it is temporary (e.g. URL expires after 15 days). To others, the page should be read-only.

The closest I can think of is Google Docs. Is there any other alternative?

Comment: There are thousands, just google the title of your question.

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress.com would let you create a blog style page which and is free without any time limit. http://wordpress.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can using dropbox service for that. Put your html files in public folder and give your friends the link. http://lifehacker.com/5528104/use-dropbox-to-share-and-host-your-web-site